# Android сокращение кода

Tags: android, инспекция-кода, adapter, setonclicklistener

У меня есть код в котором на кнопку назначен `setOnTouchListener` и `setOnClickListener` из-за реализации данного написания он занимает очень большую часть. Можно ли его как-то сократить, к примеру, можно ли его засунуть в Adapter, а потом в основном файле просто ссылаться на этот Adapter? Или может как-то по другому можно?

```
   
    private boolean firstPlayed_tasks = false;
    private View prapor_tasks_liner_parent;
    private View prapor_description_liner_parent;
    private Animation anim1;
    private Animation anim2;
    private ImageView prapor_description_img;
    private ImageView prapor_tasks_img;
    private TextView prapor_tasks_txv;
    private TextView prapor_description_txv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_list_traders_prapor, container, false);

    }

    @SuppressLint({"ResourceAsColor", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final int textColor1 = ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getContext()), R.color.color_0);
        final int textColor2 = ContextCompat.getColor(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getContext()), R.color.color_2);

        ImageButton back = requireView().findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(v -> Navigation.findNavController(view)
                .navigate(R.id.action_fragment_Menu_list_Traders_Prapor_to_fragment_Menu_list_Traders));

        prapor_description_liner_parent = requireView().findViewById(R.id.prapor_description_liner_parent);
        prapor_description_txv = requireView().findViewById(R.id.prapor_description_txv);

        prapor_tasks_liner_parent = requireView().findViewById(R.id.prapor_tasks_liner_parent);
        prapor_tasks_img = requireView().findViewById(R.id.prapor_tasks_img);
        prapor_tasks_txv = requireView().findViewById(R.id.prapor_tasks_txv);


        anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotate_1);
        anim1.setFillAfter(true);

        anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotate_2);
        anim2.setFillAfter(true);

        prapor_tasks_txv.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                    prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                    prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor1);
                    prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor1);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        });

        prapor_tasks_img.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                    prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                    prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor1);
                    prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor1);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        });

/////////////////////////////////////////

        prapor_tasks_txv.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!firstPlayed_tasks) {
                prapor_tasks_liner_parent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prapor_tasks_img.startAnimation(anim1);
                prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                firstPlayed_tasks = true;
                prapor_tasks_txv.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                prapor_tasks_img.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                // играем первую анимацию
            } else {
                prapor_tasks_liner_parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                prapor_tasks_img.startAnimation(anim2);
                prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor1);
                prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor1);
                firstPlayed_tasks = false;
                prapor_tasks_txv.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor1);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor1);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                prapor_tasks_img.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor1);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor1);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                // играем вторую анимацию
            }
        });
        prapor_tasks_img.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!firstPlayed_tasks) {
                prapor_tasks_liner_parent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prapor_tasks_img.startAnimation(anim1);
                prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                firstPlayed_tasks = true;
                prapor_tasks_txv.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                prapor_tasks_img.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                // играем первую анимацию
            } else {
                prapor_tasks_liner_parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                prapor_tasks_img.startAnimation(anim2);
                prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor1);
                prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor1);
                firstPlayed_tasks = false;
                prapor_tasks_txv.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor1);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor1);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                prapor_tasks_img.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor2);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor2);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            prapor_tasks_txv.setTextColor(textColor1);
                            prapor_tasks_img.setColorFilter(textColor1);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                // играем вторую анимацию
            }
        });
    }
}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете создать свой класс вроде такого:

```
class PraporTaskListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private NavController navController;

    PraporTaskListener (NavController navController) {
        this.navController = navController;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Здесь обрабатываете ваш клик
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_fragment_Menu_list_Traders_Prapor_to_fragment_Menu_list_Traders)); 

    }
}
```

Тогда в активити

```
back.setOnClickListener(new PraporTaskListener(Navigation.findNavController(view)))
```

Собственно так же и с другими листенерами.

Но если эти самые листенеры используются только в одном месте то подобный подход не очень практичен. Лучше вынести каждый листенер просто а отдельный метод. И тогда

```
back.setOnClickListener((View v) -> { onClickBack() });

private void onClickBack() {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используя лямбда выражения вы создаете анонимный класс прямо в месте где его необходимо использовать (если я нигде не ошибаюсь). Если вы создадите свою реализацию листенера в другом файле и унаследуете его от onClickListener(точно не помню как называется родительский класс листенера, надеюсь IDE подскажет) то в setOnClickListener можно добавить ваш собственный листенер.